# Task of type Javadoc is always up to date

Tags: gradle

I have a task of type Javadoc like this:

```
class CreateJavadocsTask extends Javadoc{
@TaskAction
def action1()
{
        project.source = project.android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        options.linkSource true
        classpath += project.files(project.android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
        failOnError false
}

}
```

This task gives an error that task is up to date as it has no source files:

Baloe is the stacktrace :

Using incremental javac compilation.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
Not using incremental javac compilation.
Using incremental javac compilation.
Not using incremental javac compilation.
Using incremental javac compilation.
All projects evaluated.
[buildinfo] Not using buildInfo properties file for this build.
Selected primary task 'createJavadocs12' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':bluetooth:createJavadocs12']
:bluetooth:createJavadocs12 (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:bluetooth:createJavadocs12
Skipping task ':bluetooth:createJavadocs12' as it has no source files.
:bluetooth:createJavadocs12 UP-TO-DATE
:bluetooth:createJavadocs12 (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.034 secs.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why do you subclass the Javadoc task?

Comment: I want to make this task a separate class and then add it in plugin class.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the inputs of the task during execution time. You will need to declare the inputs *outside* of the task action. Otherwise, Gradle won't be able to determine inputs/outputs of the task during configuration time and therefore mark it up-to-date.